# PHP: variable (array) is function?

Tags: php, arrays, exif

I dont understand the function of these characters `->` in this code:

```
$var->getImageInfo();
```

the function "getImageInfo()" populates the variable "$var".

I can use the print_r function to display all values but how do I get a specific value

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($var->getImageInfo());
echo "</pre>";
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [resolutionUnit] => 0
    [fileName] => 1.jpg
    [fileSize] => 30368 bytes
    ...
)
```

how do I get "fileSize" for instance?

Comment: *(related)* [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `$var->getImageInfo(),` the variable `$var` is an instance (also called an object) of a class. The function `getImageInfo()` is known as a class method. This is part of Object Oriented Programming, also called OOP. You can learn more about this here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

If you want to get a particular member of the array that you listed, you can simply do:

```
$image_info = $var->getImageInfo();
echo $image_info['fileSize'];
```

Answer (score 4):

$var is an object.

getImageInfo() is one method of this object - this method returns an array.

if you want to get a specific info:

```
$info = $var->getImageInfo();
$fileName = $info['fileName'];
```

Comment: You cannot do `$var->getImageInfo()['fileName'];` in PHP.

Comment: But you can do {$var->getImageInfo}['fileName']

Comment: @Rocket, I'm sorry, you are right, because {} converts values to a string. `${$var->getImageInfo()}` returns an Array to String conversion. However, if anything returns a string, you may use it as such `${$var->strRtn()}`. You can also access normally unaccessible object properties similarly, e.g., `$obj->{"illegal name"}['filename']` or `$obj->{0}['filename']`. Not that this is good practice :P

Answer (score 2):

> the function "getImageInfo()" populates the variable "$var".

No, actually it calls the method `getImageInfo()` on the object `$var`.

In order to use the returned array, do this:

```
$res = $var->getImageInfo();
print $res['fileName'];
```

Read more about working with objects in PHP in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Answer (score 2):

$var is an object (class), and `getImageInfo` is a function in that class that returns an array.  Save the resulting array into another variable to read its contents.

```
$array = $var->getImageInfo();
echo $array['fileSize'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making a call to a function inside a class with this:

```
$var->getImageInfo()
```

To get it into a regular variable to access specific keys, you just need to assign it to a normal variable a la:

```
$this = $var->getImageInfo();
echo $this['FileSize'];
```